Expectation value of angular momentum operator
In a question from the book by Cohen Tannoudji, it was asked to find the expectation value of the angular momentum operator $J$. I want to know if this is equivalent to finding $\langle J_x\rangle$, $\langle J_y\rangle$ and $\langle J_z\rangle$ or is there something else that we refer to as the 'expectation value of angular momentum operator?'
Ok, so I have to edit this question: in the book it was asked to find $\langle\vec{J}\rangle$, they gave $J$ in boldface which means vector. So, is finding the expectation of components enough, or is there something else I'm supposed to find?

What question from what chapter?

Total angular momentum is a vector,
$$
\begin{align}
    \mathbf J &= \begin{bmatrix}
           J_x \\
           J_y \\
           J_z
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$,
so an expectation value of it would be :
$$
\begin{align}
    \langle \mathbf J \rangle &= \frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N \begin{bmatrix}
           J^i_x \\
           J^i_y \\
           J^i_z
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align},$$
which basically is,
$$
\begin{align}
    \langle \mathbf J \rangle &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \langle J_x \rangle \\
           \langle J_y \rangle \\
           \langle J_z \rangle
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align},$$
or simply
$$ \langle \mathbf J \rangle  = \langle J_x \rangle \mathbf {\hat i} + \langle J_y  \rangle \mathbf {\hat j} + \langle J_z \rangle \mathbf {\hat k} $$
Hence the answer is that yes,- finding vector expected components is enough.

It most likely refers to the magnitude of the total angular momentum, $J \equiv \sqrt{<\vec{J}^2>} = \sqrt{<J_x^2 + J_y^2 + J_z^2>}$.

This is just an expected magnitude of angular momentum. Total angular momentum is a vector, so this means that average value must be vector too and not a scalar.

@AgniusVasiliauskas It is not clear from OP's question whether they are interested in the vector or just the magnitude. OP has not provided enough context to tell. OP' s literal question is: "is there something else that we refer to as the 'expectation value of angular momentum operator?'" (which is a question that none of the posted answers currently addresses).
